# Angular 2 directives & modules

Tags: angular

In older version of Angular 2 I could import directives like 
`import {CounterDirective} from './counter.directive';`

and use it.

Since the new App Module, I couldn't find any documentation about how make my own module and import it to my app. For example, I created a directive using Angular-CLI: `ng g directive counter` to create a counter to a given number. That's my directive code:

```
import { Directive,Output,Input,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[counter]'
})
export class CounterDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @Output() countoChange = new EventEmitter();
    private _timer;
    private _duration: number;
    private _countTo: number;
    private _countFrom: number;
    private _step: number;

    @Input()
    set duration(duration) {
        this._duration = parseFloat(duration);
        this.run();
    }

    @Input()
    set countTo(countTo) {
        this._countTo = parseFloat(countTo);
        this.run();
    }

    @Input()
    set countFrom(countFrom) {
        this._countFrom = parseFloat(countFrom);
        this.run();
    }

    @Input()
    set step(step) {
        this._step = parseFloat(step);
        this.run();
    }

    run() {
        var _this = this;
        clearInterval(_this._timer);

        if (isNaN(_this._duration)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (isNaN(_this._step)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (isNaN(_this._countFrom)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (isNaN(_this._countTo)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (_this._step <= 0) {
            console.info('Step must be greater than 0.');
            return false;
        }

        if (_this._duration <= 0) {
            console.info('Duration must be greater than 0.');
            return false;
        }

        if (_this._step > _this._duration*1000) {
            console.info('Step must be equal or smaller than duration.');
            return false;
        }

        var intermediate  = _this._countFrom;
        var increment     = Math.abs(_this._countTo - _this._countFrom) / ((_this._duration * 1000) / _this._step);

        _this.countoChange.emit(intermediate);

        _this._timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (_this._countTo < _this._countFrom) {
                if (intermediate <= _this._countTo) {
                    clearInterval(_this._timer);
                    _this.countoChange.emit(_this._countTo);
                } else {
                    _this.countoChange.emit(intermediate);
                    intermediate -= increment;
                }
            } else {
                if (intermediate >= _this._countTo) {
                    clearInterval(_this._timer);
                    _this.countoChange.emit(_this._countTo);
                } else {
                    _this.countoChange.emit(intermediate);
                    intermediate += increment;
                }
            }
        }, _this._step);
    }

}
```

How I can import it with my AppModule and use it?

Comment: hint: you've got a typo in the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own module for the directive, you need to both declare it in the `declarations`, and export it in the `exports`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CounterDirective ],
  exports: [ CounterDirective ]
})
class CounterModule {}
```

And whoever wants to use it, needs to import the `CounterModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CounterModule ]
})
class SomeModule {}
```

Remember that anything in `declarations` (components, directives, and pipes) are in no way inherited. This means that just importing the  `CounterModule` into the `AppModule` *will not* give access to it in all other modules. Whatever module you need to use the `CounterDirective` in, you need to import the `CounterModule`.

If the directive is only used withing the `AppModule`, then all you would need to do is add the directive to the `AppModule` `declarations`